# Make closed curve not closed. Blender 2.8

Tags: bezier-curves

I have a closed curve. I want to open the closed curve to make it not a closed curve anymore. I made the curve closed by using `Alt+C` in `Edit mode`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is click `Atl+C` again to open the closed curve.

Comment: Lol, so stupid )) Thank you ))